# Aspose word styles copy from template

Tags: java, ms-word, aspose

I am trying to use a template with predefined styles, fonts and fonts size so when I create the new document it has styles, fonts defined in my template.

This is my code:

```
private static byte[] joinSections(Document document, List<byte[]> list) throws Exception {
if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {

    document.removeAllChildren();

    for (byte[] item : list) {
        ByteArrayInputStream partInStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(item);
        Document target = new Document(partInStream);
        // Make the document appear straight after the destination documents content.
        target.getFirstSection().getPageSetup().setSectionStart(SectionStart.CONTINUOUS);
        document.appendDocument(target, ImportFormatMode.USE_DESTINATION_STYLES);
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    document.save(bs, SaveFormat.DOCX);
    return bs.toByteArray();
}

   return null;
}
```

The document is the template where styles are defined. 
The list is the list of paragraphs I want to insert into empty templates. The list is populated before calling this function

I have two issues:

1. In result document, my styles are applied, but font name and font size are inherited from source paragraphs, even I set to use USE_DESTINATION_STYLES. So for example, if my template has Arial 14 for Heading 1, and source document, from where I extracted that paragraph, for Heading 1 have font Times New Roman, in result document it will be Times New Roman? What I am missing here
2. What ever I do, I am always getting style Normal_0 in my result document. Not sure how to ignore the source and avoid having Normal_0 in my result document?

Thanks

Comment: Please try [Aspose.Words for .NET 17.8](https://downloads.aspose.com/words/net) (latest version). If the problem still remains, we need your sample 1) template and source documents, 2) console application (source code without compilation errors) to reproduce the same problem on our end, 3) Aspose.Words generated final document showing the undesired behavior and 4) expected document showing the desired output (you can create expected document using Microsoft Word.). Please upload these resources on Dropbox and share download link here for testing. 
I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.